# Clear multiple text boxes with a button in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I use .NET framework 4.

In my form, I have 41 text boxes.

I have tried with this code:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes()
        {
            Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

            func = (controls) =>
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls)
                    if (control is TextBox)
                        (control as TextBox).Clear();
                    else
                        func(control.Controls);
            };

            func(Controls);
        }
```

And this code:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes(Control.ControlCollection cc)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
            {
                TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;
                if (tb != null)
                    tb.Text = String.Empty;
                else
                    ClearTextBoxes(ctrl.Controls);
            }
        }
```

This still does not work for me.

When I tried to clear with this code `TextBoxName.Text = String.Empty;` the textbox success cleared but one textbox, still had 40 textbox again.

How do I solve this?

**EDIT**

I put in this:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ClearAllText(this);

        }

void ClearAllText(Control con)
        {
            foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                    ((TextBox)c).Clear();
                else
                    ClearAllText(c);
            }
        }
```

but still not work.

**Edit**

[image]

I used panels and splitter.

Comment: web form or win form?

Comment: in Win form @MicrosoftDN

Comment: Are there any textboxes on panels or other containers?

Comment: Yes i have panel and spliter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
void ClearAllText(Control con)
{
    foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
    {
      if (c is TextBox)
         ((TextBox)c).Clear();
      else
         ClearAllText(c);
    }
}
```

To use the above code, simply do this:

```
ClearAllText(this);
```

Comment: @Alexbelek: What is the error or problem? This solution works for me.

Comment: i think it works well , OP should clearly state the problem where he is stuck.

Comment: i edited my question, i put `ClearAllText(this);` in my button name btnClear. but still not work

Comment: @Alexbelek You have just pasted the code not mentioned any error. How can anybody know your problem?

Comment: Can we have a screenshot of you win form application? also, add a breakpoint inside the foreach loop, does it go inside the loop?

Comment: i try to answer @User2012384 question .

Comment: Edited my question, there is my screen shoot.

Comment: Try to put the "ID" of the panel which contains "Seksi", "Kepala" etc.. instead of "this"

Comment: i put **the name of panel** instead of `this`. and it works now.... the name of panel is `pnlData`

Comment: This is the only one the worked after testing out many version. Thanks so much for saving my day.

Comment: thank you, this answer worked for me. the only small problem I faced was adding the "TextBox" code. and I tried "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" in both lines. and it worked. hope this would be helpfull.

Comment: @Anu Hello Thanks for your response, to simplify, you can try adding using System.Windows.Forms; on the top so you don't need to explicitly type "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
 private void RecursiveClearTextBoxes(Control.ControlCollection cc)
 {
   foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
   {
     TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;
     if (tb != null)
     tb.Clear();

    else
    RecursiveClearTextBoxes(ctrl.Controls);
   }
```

Comment: But what if `ctrl` doesn't have any child controls? For something a little bit more proper, look at F.R.I.E.N.D.S.' answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** You need to go through all the `Controls` in the `Form`.

**Step2:** if a `Control` is `TextBox` then call `Clear()` function.

Try This:

```
        void clearText(Control control)
        {
            foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                    ((TextBox)c).Clear();
                else
                    clearText(c);
            }
        }
        public void ModifyControl<T>(Control root, Action<T> action) where T : Control
        {
            if (root is T)
                action((T)root);
            // Call ModifyControl on all child controls
            foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
                ModifyControl<T>(control, action);
        }
        private void button5_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           clearText(this);
           ModifyControl<TextBox>(splitContainer1, tb => tb.Text = "");
        }
```

Comment: I think you need recursion, this will just clear the textboxes in the control collection, not the textboxes which are children to the controls in the collection.

Comment: @Tobberoth: yes we need recursion here. Thank you for your valuable point.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well for myself.

```
void ClearTextBoxes(DependencyObject dObject)
{
    TextBox tb = dObject as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
        tb.Text = null;

    foreach (DependencyObject obj in dObject.GetChildObjects())
        ClearTextBoxes(obj);
}
```

And then simply call on it as you wish, for example, I am clearing all TextBoxes in a TabControl, which also includes the Tabs not on screen:

```
ClearTextBoxes(CustomerTabControl);
```