# Clearing all data on tab page when clicking No Button

Tags: c#, tabpage

in my application im submitting a data to the db on a tabControls page(page:tabPage2) and i want when hitting the submit button first saving data to db(im achieving this) the a question will ask anything will be done? if the user hit the no button all fields on tabpage2 will reset. so i wrote a script like below but it is not clearing fields.

```
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl1.Controls.Count; i++)
            {

                if (this.tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
                {
                    if (tabPage2.Controls[i] is TextBox)
                    {
                        tabPage2.Controls[i].Text = "";
                    }

                    if (tabPage2.Controls[i] is ComboBox)
                    {
                        tabPage2.Controls[i].Text = "";
                    }

                    if (tabPage2.Controls[i] is PictureBox)
                    {
                        tabPage2.Controls[i].Text = "";
                    }

                    if (tabPage2.Controls[i] is RadioButton)
                    {
                        tabPage2.Controls[i].Text = "";
                    }

                }


            }

        }
```

Comment: This post might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065408/clear-multiple-text-boxes-with-a-button-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you have a specific class for the page you need to clear, or is it an external class you can't modify?  Do you need it to handle pages built dynamically, or do you just need to clear a single specific form/control class (or a few specific types)?

Answer (score 2):

If you control the class for the page layout within the specific tab page you want to clear, it's probably best to create a public or internal method in that class (such as `Clear()`) which can access each of its member controls and clear them directly.  That's the easiest approach, and it should usually apply.

If you *instead* need it to handle a page with an unknown structure, you might need an approach like:

```
private void ClearControls(Control parentControl)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        TextBox ctrlText;
        ComboBox ctrlCombo;
        PictureBox ctrlPicture;
        RadioButton ctrlRadio;

        // Pay careful attention to the parentheses...
        if ((ctrlText = ctrl as TextBox) != null)
        {
            ctrlText.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else if ((ctrlCombo = ctrl as ComboBox) != null)
        {
            ctrlCombo.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else if ((ctrlPicture = ctrl as PictureBox) != null)
        {
            // Logic to clear a PictureBox called ctrlPicture
        }
        else if ((ctrlRadio = ctrl as RadioBox) != null)
        {
            // Logic to clear a RadioButton called ctrlRadio
        }
        else if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            ClearControls(ctrl); // Recursively clear contained controls.
        }
    }
}
```

With a call to start it off from the original handler:

```
if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    ClearControls(this.tabControl1);
```

Comment: This indeed fixes a few things in the original code but the problem of possibly nested controls remains. Still, +1.

Comment: Yeah, also I noticed I was mixing `ctrl` from your example with the original for loop which didn't define or assign it.  I cleaned it up and added recursion (although further refinement is possible such as to limit what types are recursively traversed).

Comment: @Crono Also, my first paragraph is really the preferred approach (if possible), which handles group-nested controls without issue (they're just members of the parent user control class).  If you include other user controls within it you just need a Clear() method in them to call as part of the parent's Clear() method.  Hopefully, that's straightforwardly obvious.

Comment: I most certainly agree.

Answer (score 0):

You are itering over the collection of `TabControl` child controls, not actual `TabPage`'s.

Change your code to this instead:

```
if (dr == DialogResult.Yes && this.tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
{
    foreach (var ctrl in tabPage2.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox || ctrl is ComboBox || ctrl is PictureBox || ctrl is RadioButton)
        {
            ctrl.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I should say though than setting the `Text` property to "" for controls other than `TextBox` feels rather wrong to me. As you'll find out, this won't work for combos, images and radio buttons.

Also if you have controls nested into panels or the like they won't be cleared. Containers have their own nested collection of controls, which in turn can also be containers, and so on and on.

IMHO **it would be far better for you to explicitely reset form controls one by one rather than trying to find them dynamically on your form**. This way you'll be free to move your controls around at design time without ever worrying about breaking the resetting logic.

Additional suggestion: you can also attach your controls at design time to an instance of your own `IExtenderProvider` component which will take care of resetting controls appropriately based on their type.

Comment: Wouldn't that reset the Text of labels on the page as well?

Comment: @RobParker yeah I figured that out about 30 seconds after posting my answer. :) I'll admit I don't ever clear out form data this way. :p

Comment: yea you are rigt it shouldnt be text property of picturebox or radio button but in your code ctrl.text is syntax error becasue a variable can not get a control property. did you try this code on your own debugger?

Comment: @paradoxIST Copy and paste the *exact* error message you have please.

Comment: @paradoxIST that can't be right. Let me try on my side, I'll come back at you asap.

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: @paradoxIST it compiles and run just fine on my side. Out of curiosity, what happens if you change `var ctrl` to `Control ctrl`?

Comment: thanks crono. it compiled. but only for textboxes :) combobox is still have values. do you know the reason?

Comment: @paradoxIST for combos you should set `SelectedIndex` to -1.