# Clear Multiple Textbox at Once

Tags: vb.net

I have the following textboxes and want to delete them faster.

```
TxtDrawA1.Clear
TxtDrawA2.Clear
TxtDrawA3.Clear
TxtDrawA4.Clear
TxtDrawA5.Clear
TxtDrawA6.Clear
TxtDrawA7.Clear
TxtDrawA8.Clear
and so on...
```

Comment: Do you want to clear all the text boxes on the Form or only some of them.

Comment: Not all, just those starting with TxtdrawA (1-2-3-4-5-6-7)

Comment: @FerdoPerdana - you said 1 through 7 but show TxtDrawA8 in the example. What do you mean by. 'delete them faster"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear multiple text boxes with a button in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065408/clear-multiple-text-boxes-with-a-button-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to find them no matter what container they are in (they can all even be in different containers).  This approach also demonstrates how to get those controls "in order":

```
Dim tb As TextBox
Dim ctl As Control
For i As Integer = 1 To 8
    ctl = Me.Controls.Find("TxtDrawA" & i, True).FirstOrDefault
    If Not IsNothing(ctl) AndAlso TypeOf (ctl) Is TextBox Then
        tb = DirectCast(ctl, TextBox)
        ' ... do stuff with "tb" ...
        tb.Clear()
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!

You could try iterating through the textboxes like this:

```
For Each txtb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
     If txtb.Name.StartsWith("TxtDrawA")
         txtb.Clear
     End If
Next
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I saw at another answer, you might need to clear the textboxes inside Tab3.TabPage(0). In this case all you have to do is to replace Me.Controls. ... with Tab3.TabPage(0).Controls. ...